# Algorithm or code for converting OMML to MathML

Tags: algorithm, mathml, omml

I am in the process of converting Word doc standard equations (OMML) to MathML using flash or Flex, please help me out by providing simple Algorithm or code snippet.

Thanks in advance,
Mani

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11663161/797393

Answer (score 3):

There is an XSLT 1 stylesheet that does that conversion provided by microsoft as part of the Word Distribution, it is what handles placing MathML on the clipboard in Word. Typically installed as something like

```
c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office14/OMML2MML.XSL
```

There is some discussion of an early version of this at

http://dpcarlisle.blogspot.co.uk/2007/04/xhtml-and-mathml-from-office-20007.html

Comment: Where is this file located on a Mac?

Comment: on my PC, XLS file is located on C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16

Comment: in same folder, you can also find MML2OMML.xsl !

Answer (score 1):

here is snippet of a C# class I was working on a few days ago ... I know it's too late .. but for less future pain.

I think it's not very different in Action Script

the file `OMML2MML.xsl` is located at `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office12\`  as mentioned by @David the xsl file is used for placing MathML on the clipboard in Word and converting OMML to MML too.

```
public static string OMML(string omml)
{
    XslCompiledTransform xslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
    xslTransform.Load("OMML2MML.xsl");

    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(omml)))
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = xslTransform.OutputSettings.Clone();

            // Configure xml writer to omit xml declaration.
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
            settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

            XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings);

            // Transform our OfficeMathML to MathML
            xslTransform.Transform(reader, xw);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8);
            string MathML = sr.ReadToEnd();
            return MathML;
        }
    }
}
```